# Formula with dynamic number of variables

Tags: r, formula, r-formula

Suppose, there is some data.frame **foo_data_frame** and one wants to find regression of the target column **Y** by some others columns. For that purpose usualy some formula and model are used. For example:

```
linear_model <- lm(Y ~ FACTOR_NAME_1 + FACTOR_NAME_2, foo_data_frame)
```

That does job well if the formula is coded statically. If it is desired to root over several models with the constant number of dependent variables (say, 2) it can be treated like that:

```
for (i in seq_len(factor_number)) {
  for (j in seq(i + 1, factor_number)) {
    linear_model <- lm(Y ~ F1 + F2, list(Y=foo_data_frame$Y,
                                         F1=foo_data_frame[[i]],
                                         F2=foo_data_frame[[j]]))
    # linear_model further analyzing...
  }
}
```

My question is how to do the same affect when the number of variables is changing dynamically during program running?

```
for (number_of_factors in seq_len(5)) {
   # Then root over subsets with #number_of_factors cardinality.
   for (factors_subset in all_subsets_with_fixed_cardinality) {
     # Here I want to fit model with factors from factors_subset.
     linear_model <- lm(Does R provide smth to write here?)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! your middle example made me realise I didn't need the solution to your question and could do something much simpler!

Answer (score 118, accepted):

See `?as.formula`, e.g.:

```
factors <- c("factor1", "factor2")
as.formula(paste("y~", paste(factors, collapse="+")))
# y ~ factor1 + factor2
```

where `factors` is a character vector containing the names of the factors you want to use in the model. This you can paste into an `lm` model, e.g.:

```
set.seed(0)
y <- rnorm(100)
factor1 <- rep(1:2, each=50)
factor2 <- rep(3:4, 50)
lm(as.formula(paste("y~", paste(factors, collapse="+"))))

# Call:
# lm(formula = as.formula(paste("y~", paste(factors, collapse = "+"))))

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)      factor1      factor2  
#    0.542471    -0.002525    -0.147433
```

Answer (score 74):

An oft forgotten function is `reformulate`. From `?reformulate`:

> `reformulate` creates a formula from a character vector.

---

A simple example:

```
listoffactors <- c("factor1","factor2")
reformulate(termlabels = listoffactors, response = 'y')
```

will yield this formula:

`y ~ factor1 + factor2`

---

Although not explicitly documented, you can also add interaction terms:

```
listofintfactors <- c("(factor3","factor4)^2")
reformulate(termlabels = c(listoffactors, listofintfactors), 
    response = 'y')
```

will yield:

`y ~ factor1 + factor2 + (factor3 + factor4)^2`

Comment: @JorisMeys And it's so much nicer as it allows adding interaction terms! I've been looking for a similar solution for years..

Comment: What if the x variables contain spaces? Say "factor 1" , "factor 2" etc..

Answer (score 12):

Another option could be to use a matrix in the formula:

```
Y = rnorm(10)
foo = matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)
factors=c(1,5,8)

lm(Y ~ foo[,factors])
```

Comment: +1, but be aware of the fact this doesn't allow to use interaction effects. For that one can construct a model matrix as well (see `?model.matrix` )

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually need a formula.  This works:

```
lm(data_frame[c("Y", "factor1", "factor2")])
```

as does this:

```
v <- c("Y", "factor1", "factor2")
do.call("lm", list(bquote(data_frame[.(v)])))
```

Comment: +1 Very correct, but again, you'd have to use model.matrix to construct a matrix with interaction effects.

Answer (score 1):

I generally solve this by changing the name of my response column. It is easier to do dynamically, and possibly cleaner.

```
model_response <- "response_field_name"
setnames(model_data_train, c(model_response), "response") #if using data.table
model_gbm <- gbm(response ~ ., data=model_data_train, ...)
```