# Combining cbind and paste in linear model

Tags: r, string, formula, lm, cbind

I would like to know how can I come up with a `lm` formula syntax that would enable me to use `paste` together with `cbind` for multiple multivariate regression.

## Example

In my model I have a set of variables, which corresponds to the primitive example below:

```
data(mtcars)
depVars <- paste("mpg", "disp")
indepVars <- paste("qsec", "wt", "drat")
```

## Problem

I would like to create a model with my `depVars` and `indepVars`. The model, typed by hand, would look like that:

```
modExmple <- lm(formula = cbind(mpg, disp) ~ qsec + wt + drat, data = mtcars)
```

---

*I'm interested in generating the same formula without referring to variable names and only using `depVars` and `indepVars` vectors defined above.*

---

### Attempt 1

For example, what I had on mind would correspond to:

```
mod1 <- lm(formula = formula(paste(cbind(paste(depVars, collapse = ",")), " ~ ",
                                   indepVars)), data = mtcars)
```

### Attempt 2

I tried this as well:

```
mod2 <- lm(formula = formula(cbind(depVars), paste(" ~ ",
                                                   paste(indepVars, 
                                                         collapse = " + "))),
           data = mtcars)
```

---

## Side notes

- I found a number of [good examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951442/formula-with-dynamic-number-of-variables) on how to use `paste` with formula but I would like to know how I can combine with `cbind`.
- This is mostly a syntax a question; in my real data I've a number of variables I would like to introduce to the model and making use of the previously generated vector is more parsimonious and makes the code more presentable. In effect, I'm only interested in creating a formula object that would contain `cbind` with variable names corresponding to one vector and the remaining variables corresponding to another vector.
- In a word, I want to arrive at the formula in `modExample` *without* having to type variable names.

Comment: The `depVars` is a `string` with space.  You can use `paste(c("qsec", "wt", "drat"), collapse='+')`

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the contribution, I'm guessing that it should be something on those lines but: the syntax `formula(cbind(paste(depVars)), " ~ ", paste(indepVars, collapse='+')), data = mtcars)` won't work. Where I get stuck is on combining `cbind` / `paste`.

Comment: Maybe making use of the [`reformulate`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13371468/1655567) would help?

Comment: Looks like the `reformulate` might help.  I think the problem is with the `paste(depVars))`

Comment: @akrun Yup, I also see that it would be better if vectors with variable names would be defined via `c()` not `paste()`.

Comment: @akrun Enjoy your tea :) I may have one as well. By the way, this almost works `reformulate(paste("cbind(", paste(depVars, collapse = " , "), ")  ~ ", paste(indepVars, collapse = " + ")))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think it works.

```
data(mtcars)
depVars <- c("mpg", "disp")
indepVars <- c("qsec", "wt", "drat")

lm(formula(paste('cbind(',
                 paste(depVars, collapse = ','),
                 ') ~ ',
                 paste(indepVars, collapse = '+'))), data = mtcars)
```

Comment: Ha! Thanks very much. We were getting there slowly, I had a hunch that there will be something with `cbind(`. BTW, it's an interesting way of writing code, like infamous `concatenate` in Excel. Thanks very much for your contribution!

Answer (score 3):

All the solutions below use these definitions:

```
depVars <- c("mpg", "disp")
indepVars <- c("qsec", "wt", "drat")
```

**1) character string formula** Create a character string representing the formula and then run `lm` using `do.call`.  Note that the the formula shown in the output displays correctly and is written out.

```
fo <- sprintf("cbind(%s) ~ %s", toString(depVars), paste(indepVars, collapse = "+"))
do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(mtcars)))
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = "cbind(mpg, disp) ~ qsec+wt+drat", data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
             mpg       disp    
(Intercept)   11.3945  452.3407
qsec           0.9462  -20.3504
wt            -4.3978   89.9782
drat           1.6561  -41.1148
```

**1a)** This would also work:

```
fo <- sprintf("cbind(%s) ~.", toString(depVars))
do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(mtcars[c(depVars, indepVars)])))
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = cbind(mpg, disp) ~ qsec + wt + drat, data = mtcars[c(depVars, 
    indepVars)])

Coefficients:
             mpg       disp    
(Intercept)   11.3945  452.3407
qsec           0.9462  -20.3504
wt            -4.3978   89.9782
drat           1.6561  -41.1148
```

**2) reformulate** @akrun and @Konrad, in comments below the question suggest using `reformulate`.   This approach produces a `"formula"` object whereas the ones above produce a character string as the formula.  (If this were desired for the prior solutions above it would be possible using `fo <- formula(fo)` .)  Note that it is important that the response argument to `reformulate` be a call object and not a character string or else `reformulate` will interpret the character string as the name of a single variable.

```
fo <- reformulate(indepVars, parse(text = sprintf("cbind(%s)", toString(depVars)))[[1]])
do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(mtcars)))
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = cbind(mpg, disp) ~ qsec + wt + drat, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
             mpg       disp    
(Intercept)   11.3945  452.3407
qsec           0.9462  -20.3504
wt            -4.3978   89.9782
drat           1.6561  -41.1148
```

**3) lm.fit** Another way that does not use a formula at all is:

```
m <- as.matrix(mtcars)
fit <- lm.fit(cbind(1, m[, indepVars]), m[, depVars])
```

The output is a list with these components:

```
> names(fit)
[1] "coefficients"  "residuals"     "effects"       "rank"         
[5] "fitted.values" "assign"        "qr"            "df.residual"
```