# Aggregate columns specified in list

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm aggregating multiple columns in an R data frame using the following method:

```
data = data.frame(X=c(1, 3, 3), Y=c(2, 3, 3), Z=c(5, 6, 7), ID=c(10, 11, 12))
with(data, aggregate(cbind(Z, ID), list(X=X, Y=Y), c))
```

However, I want to select columns using a list variable. I've tried some intricate `paste` statements looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129225/combining-cbind-and-paste-in-linear-model) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208/aggregate-summarize-multiple-variables-per-group-i-e-sum-mean-etc), but I get error messages like "object 'Z' not found".

How do I do this in a short-hand, easy-to-read manner using base R, preferably without libraries, `do.call` or hard-to-read `paste` statements full of parenthesis and apostrophes? Ideally:

```
k = c("Z", "ID")
aggregate(magic(k), list(X=X, Y=Y), data, c)
```

Comment: `aggregate(data[k], data[c("X","Y")], c)` covered in `?aggregate` that there are two forms of syntax.

Comment: @Frank: `aggregate(data[k], data[c("X","Y")], c)` is short and beautiful! You may post this as a suggested answer. I doubt there will be better suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
aggregate(data[k], data[c("X","Y")], c)
```

A data.frame is a list, so `by=data[c("X","Y")]` works as needed here.

Comment: Posting because I couldn't find a dupe and the OP suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = data.frame(X=c(1, 3, 3), Y=c(2, 3, 3), Z=c(5, 6, 7), ID=c(10, 11, 12))

# I would use quote:
by.expr <- quote(cbind(Z, ID))
with(data, aggregate(eval(by.expr), list(X=X, Y=Y), c))

# list-version:
by.l <- list("Z", "ID")
by.expr <- parse(text = paste("cbind(", unlist(by.l), ")"))
with(data, aggregate(eval(by.expr), list(X=X, Y=Y), c))
```