# Dynamic formula with dynamic factor - R

Tags: r, rstudio, formula

I take this example ([Formula with dynamic number of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951442/formula-with-dynamic-number-of-variables)) and kindly ask you for an extension of the problem

```
factors <- c("factor1", "factor2")
as.formula(paste("y~", paste(factors, collapse="+")))
# y ~ factor1 + factor2
```

My problem is similar but with a lot of different specifications:

```
specification_vec <- c(0,1,2,3)

for (sp_vec in specification_vec){
specification_sel <- sp_vec


core_spec <- c("factor1core", "factor2core", "factor3core", "factor4core" ) # ->0
base1_spec <- c(core_spec, "factor5","factor6","factor7") #->1
base2_spec <- c(core_spec, "factor8","factor9","factor10") #->2
base3_spec <- c(base2_spec, "factor15") #->3

#tried solution Not Working    

if (specification_sel == 0){
Eqfor <- as.formula(paste("y~", paste(core_spec, collapse = "+")))
} else if (specification_sel == sp_vec) {
Eqfor <- as.formula(paste("y~", paste(paste0("base",sp_vec,"_vars"), collapse="+")))
}

#lot of other stuff

} #this closes the loop
```

Any idea?

Edit: Thanks to d.b comment. This should work.

```
  specification_vec <- c(0,1,2,3)

  for (sp_vec in specification_vec){
    specification_sel <- sp_vec


    core_spec <- c("factor1core", "factor2core", "factor3core", "factor4core" ) # ->0
    base1_spec <- c(core_spec, "factor5","factor6","factor7") #->1
    base2_spec <- c(core_spec, "factor8","factor9","factor10") #->2
    base3_spec <- c(base2_spec, "factor15") #->3

    #Working    

    if (specification_sel == 0){
      Eqfor <- as.formula(paste("y~", paste(core_spec, collapse = "+")))
    } else if (specification_sel == sp_vec) {
      Eqfor <- reformulate(eval(parse(text = paste0("base",sp_vec,"_spec"))), "y")

        }

    #lot of other stuff
   print(Eqfor) 
  } #this closes the loop
```

Comment: try `reformulate(factors, "y")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I might need a loop to change the factors array, otherwise I need to nest too many else if for each specification