# How to dynamically name variables in formula in lm() function?

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is a way to "predefine" parameters to functions like lm, glmer(lme4), glm, or home made functions.

I'll try to show my question with a small dataframe

```
y1<-(rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1))
y2<-(rnorm(n = 100, mean = 4, sd = 1))
x1 <- letters[1:2]; x1<- rep(x1, times =50 )
x2 <- letters[2:3]; x1<- rep(x1, times =50 )
x3 <- letters[4:5]; x1<- rep(x1, times =50 )
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(y1,y2,x1,x2,x3));df$y1<-as.numeric(df$y1);df$y2<-as.numeric(df$y2)
```

then I can easily fit lm like this

```
model <- lm(y1 ~x1, data=df)
```

However, what I am interested in being able to do is something like this

```
#first define list of predictors 
predictor_vector<- c("x1","x2","x3")
```

And then use the names (strings) as a parameter in the `lm()` function.

In this example, I am using `lm()` and attempting to dynamically construct the regression as so:

```
model <- lm(y1 ~predictor_vector[1], data=df)
model <- lm(y1 ~predictor_vector[2], data=df)
model <- lm(y1 ~predictor_vector[3], data=df)
```

The example above doesn't work.

I am very grateful for any input on this topic and hope my example and explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core issue to understand here is that `lm()` takes a type `formula` as the first parameter that specifies the regression.

You've created a vector of strings (characters) but R won't dynamically generated the formula for you in the function call - the ability to just type variable names as a formula is a convenience but not practical when you are attempting to be dynamic.

To simplify your example, start with:

```
y1 <- (rnorm(n = 10, mean = 0, sd = 1))
x1 <- (rnorm(n = 10, mean = 0, sd = 1))
x2 <- (rnorm(n = 10, mean = 0, sd = 1))
x3 <- (rnorm(n = 10, mean = 0, sd = 1))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(y1,x1,x2,x3))

predictors = c("x1", "x2", "x3")
```

Now you can dynamically create a formula as as concatenated string (`paste0`) and convert it to a formula. Then pass this formula to your `lm()` call:

```
form1 = as.formula(paste0("y1~", predictors[1]))

lm(form1, data = df)
```

As akrun pointed out, you can then start doing things like create loops to dynamically generate these.

You can also do things like:

```
my_formula = as.formula(paste0("y1~", paste0(predictors, collapse="+")))

## generates y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3
lm(my_formula, data = df)
```

See also: [Formula with dynamic number of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951442/formula-with-dynamic-number-of-variables)

One of the answers on that page also mentions akrun's alternative way of doing this, using the function `reformulate`. From `?reformulate`:

> reformulate creates a formula from a character vector. If length(termlabels) > 1, its elements are concatenated with +. Non-syntactic names (e.g. containing spaces or special characters; see make.names) must be protected with backticks (see examples). A non-parseable response still works for now, back compatibly, with a deprecation warning.

Comment: This way is (unfortunately) fairly widespread but there’s absolutely no need to go the detour via strings. R allows direct metaprogramming on actual, unevaluated R expressions. Instead of moderately complex string operations you could write e.g. `bquote(y1 ~ .(as.name('x1')))`.

Comment: @izyda, thanks a lot for your detailed and helpful answer! All you suggest works well and your explanation also helped me understand why it didn't work in the first place.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, 
I am certain there is some great information in your comment but unfortunately i do not understand what you mean. What izyda suggested seems work for great in the example. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

We may use a loop.  Construct the formula with `reformulate` or `paste`, and apply the `lm` to return the models in a `list`

```
out <- lapply(predictor_vector, function(x)
     lm(reformulate(x, response = "y1"), data = df))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion it works well to use the apply approach